# How to permanently set $PATH on Raspbian GNU/Linux 10

Tags: bash, path, raspberry-pi

I want to store my samba binary path to the global `$PATH` variable on my rpi4 but it did not work as expected.
I've created a file `samba-binary-path.sh` in the folder `/etc/profile.sh` and made it with `chmod +x` executable.

The file `samba-binary-path.sh` contains the following:

`export PATH=/usr/local/samba/bin/:/usr/local/samba/sbin/:$PATH`

Furthermore I have `export PATH=/usr/local/samba/bin/:/usr/local/samba/sbin/:$PATH` also saved in the file `/etc/environment`.

Now comes the crazy part. When I execute my script on my cli it work as intended but when it get started from another process the path variable missing my samba binary path.

The affected code block:

```
#!/bin/bash
BINDIR=$(samba -b | grep 'BINDIR' | grep -v 'SBINDIR' | awk '{print $NF}')
[[ -z $BINDIR ]] && printf "Cannot find the 'samba' binary, is it installed?"
```

For debbuging purposes I piped the `$PATH` variable to `/var/log/syslog`.

Here is the result:

- Executed on cli: `$PATH=/usr/local/samba/bin/:/usr/local/samba/sbin/:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin`
- Executed from other process: `$PATH=/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin`

Where do I specify the path so that the samba binary could be always found?

Regards,

Ronny

Comment: `I have export PATH ..  in the file /etc/environment` that's not the format of `environment` file.

Comment: `when it get started from another process` What "another process"? `Executed from other process:` What "other process"? Which process?

Comment: Yes, you are right. I have once again removed it from `/etc/environment`

Comment: Otoh, `samba -b | awk '/^BINDIR$/{print $NF}'` maybe

Comment: It is about the following script [Link](https://wiki.samba.org/index.php/Configure_DHCP_to_update_DNS_records_with_BIND9#Create_the_script_for_the_updates).

It is executed by the DHCP server 'isc-dhcp-server' when an IP address lease is assigned or deleted.

dhcpd.conf [link](https://wiki.samba.org/index.php/Configure_DHCP_to_update_DNS_records_with_BIND9#Modify_the_dhcp_conf_file)

Comment: `# You may need to ensure that you have a useful path
# If you have 'path' problems, Uncomment the next line and adjust for
# your setup e.g. self-compiled Samba #export PATH=/usr/local/samba/bin:` from that link

Comment: The script creator included this in the script yesterday on my advice.

Comment: I am/was looking for a global solution to the $PATH problem, which is why I asked this question here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How to permanently set $PATH on Raspbian GNU/Linux 10

To explicitly permanently change PATH for all possible environments that do not have `PATH` is explicitly set, like a new non-interactive non-login shell that does not inherit `PATH` from the parent process, recompile bash with different value of [DEFAULT_PATH_VALUE](https://github.com/bminor/bash/blob/f3a35a2d601a55f337f8ca02a541f8c033682247/config-top.h#L65) (there's a `./configure` option for it if I remember correctly).

> Where do I specify the path so that the samba binary could be always found?

You specify it in your script.

```
PATH=$PATH:/some/path
# or explicitly
bindir=$(/the/path/to/samba -b ....)
```

You could also explicitly invoke a login shell when running the script, ergo sourcing `/etc/profile*` stuff.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I thought there might be a system wide variable where I can enter that. I already knew that I can specify the paths in the script. Then I will continue to do it that way. :-)